# How to pin to taskbar using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-7, taskbar

How can I pin some programs to taskbar on Windows 7 using
PowerShell? Please explain step-by-step.

And How to modify the following code to pin a folder to
taskbar? For Example

```c
$folder = $shell.Namespace('D:\Work')
```

In this path, `example` named folder.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can invoke a `Verb` (Pin to Taskbar) using the Shell.Application COM object. Here's some example code:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/b66434f1-4b3f-4a94-8dc3-e406eb30b750

The example is somewhat complicated. Here is a simplified version:

```
$shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
$folder = $shell.Namespace('C:\Windows')    
$item = $folder.Parsename('notepad.exe')
$verb = $item.Verbs() | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Pin to Tas&kbar'}
if ($verb) {$verb.DoIt()}
```

Comment: typo on 'Pin to Tas&kbar' or is 'Pin to Taskbar'?

Comment: It actually has the `&` because it's used for the hot key you can press in the file's right-click context menu.

Comment: ok, but functions in the link show a $verb.replace( "&","") ... Can't test it now..

Comment: Yea, I think just to make it less ugly to pass as a parameter. Strange thing... this is crashing PowerShell in Win8 Beta but works in Win7. It pinned once in Win8 for me but crashed after.

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen :)It works successfully. Thanks Andy, I think this is the shortest solution for that.

Comment: The downside to this approach is that it parses English text to find the verb.  The solution from Steven Penny, which uses invokeverb('taskbarpin'), is more appropriate since it uses an identifier that is likely to be the same across locales.

Comment: Could you have a look at my problem?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476927/powershell-cannot-find-some-verbs-of-executable/37477179?noredirect=1#comment62452193_37477179

Answer (score 23):

Another way

```c
$sa = new-object -c shell.application
$pn = $sa.namespace($env:windir).parsename('notepad.exe')
$pn.invokeverb('taskbarpin')
```

Or unpin

```c
$pn.invokeverb('taskbarunpin')
```

Note: notepad.exe may not be under `%windir%`, it may exist under `%windir%\system32` for server OS's.

Comment: @SliverNinja: an edit you made to this post was rolled back. Since the post author is now permanently banned from the network, you may re-add your amendment if you wish. (I shall refrain from doing so, as it is not my area of expertise).

Answer (score 10):

As I needed to do this via PowerShell, I utilized the methods provided by others here. This is my implementation I ended up adding to a PowerShell module:

```
function Get-ComFolderItem() {
    [CMDLetBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $Path
    )

    $ShellApp = New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application'

    $Item = Get-Item $Path -ErrorAction Stop

    if ($Item -is [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
        $ComFolderItem = $ShellApp.Namespace($Item.Directory.FullName).ParseName($Item.Name)
    } elseif ($Item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
        $ComFolderItem = $ShellApp.Namespace($Item.Parent.FullName).ParseName($Item.Name)
    } else {
        throw "Path is not a file nor a directory"
    }

    return $ComFolderItem
}

function Install-TaskBarPinnedItem() {
    [CMDLetBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.IO.FileInfo] $Item
    )

    $Pinned = Get-ComFolderItem -Path $Item

    $Pinned.invokeverb('taskbarpin')
}

function Uninstall-TaskBarPinnedItem() {
    [CMDLetBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.IO.FileInfo] $Item
    )

    $Pinned = Get-ComFolderItem -Path $Item

    $Pinned.invokeverb('taskbarunpin')
}
```

## Example usage for a provisioning script:

```
# The order results in a left to right ordering
$PinnedItems = @(
    'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe'
    'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
)

# Removing each item and adding it again results in an idempotent ordering
# of the items. If order doesn't matter, there is no need to uninstall the
# item first.
foreach($Item in $PinnedItems) {
    Uninstall-TaskBarPinnedItem -Item $Item
    Install-TaskBarPinnedItem   -Item $Item
}
```

Comment: Seems that doesn't work ok Win Server 2016 DataCenter.

Comment: Does not do anything on Windows 10 Pro for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720595/pin-program-to-taskbar-using-ps-in-windows-10 might be an alternative (not tested yet)

Comment: None of this is wotking for a German Windows 11.