# How to get programmatically context menu simulating SHIFT key pressed down?

Tags: c#, windows, object, powershell, contextmenu

As there is difference between standard context menu and between the one that appears when SHIFT key is pressed down, I would like to know how to get programmatically these values. I'm mostly interested in pinning to start menu shortcut items located in 'Start menu\Programs\', that are without shift key pressed down impossible to pin (option is not shown) - this behavior is valid for all listed shortcut files in start/programs. And furthermore I would like to do that scripted way. Ideally if it could be Powershell or C# code ;)

Screenshot of context menu without SHIFT key pressed down:

[image]

Screenshot of context menu with SHIFT key pressed down:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to show the contextmenu or do you want to pin to start menu?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739772/how-to-pin-to-taskbar-using-powershell) what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mark it as solved once your comments provided. If you would like to get reputation, please answer it and I will make mark it as an answer. I just went through all my opened questions and found this, which I forgot to close.