# Pin program to taskbar using PS in Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am trying to pin a program to the taskbar in Windows 10 (RTM) using this code:

```bsh
$shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application"  
$folder = $shell.Namespace((Join-Path $env:SystemRoot System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0))
$item = $folder.Parsename('powershell_ise.exe')
$item.invokeverb('taskbarpin');
```

This worked on Windows 8.1, but no longer works on Windows 10.

If I execute `$item.Verbs()`, I get these:

```
Application Parent Name
----------- ------ ----
                   &Open
                   Run as &administrator
                   &Pin to Start

                   Restore previous &versions

                   Cu&t
                   &Copy
                   Create &shortcut
                   &Delete
                   Rena&me
                   P&roperties
```

As you can see, there is no verb for pinning it to the taskbar. If I right click that specific file, however, the option is there:
[image: Available verbs in UI]

**Questions:**
Am I missing something?
Is there a new way in Windows 10 to pin a program to the taskbar?

Comment: maybe is a case for microsoft connect? It seem that the verb is missing! But a lookup in the regedit seem present!

Comment: @CB. Good idea. Here is the report: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1609288/pin-to-taskbar-no-longer-working-in-windows-10 Although, I have a feeling that it might be intentional, to stop programs from "polluting" the taskbar?

Comment: Yes,  can be,  but anyway Msft must start to documents this kind of change!  Ï'll up vote on connect

Comment: Eww... I will have a few login scripts to change if this is not resolved by the time we move to win10 in our org.

Comment: You call `ParseName` with a lowercase N, since it's a COM object and not a powershell method, it may make a difference. If I right click a folder, I see a 'Pin to Start', but not 'Pin To Taskbar'

Comment: @Eris No, this doesn't make a difference. And I am not trying to pin a folder but an executable :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I suspect this is intentionally broken.

Comment: `Join-Path $env:SystemRoot System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` is this still the path for powershell in Win 10?

Comment: @Xalorous Sure. See screenshot above

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thanks. I see it now.

Comment: It seems that a shortcut is created in `"$env:appdata\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\Taskbar\"` folder. That's trivial to do in Powershell but that shortcut itself is not enough. I see that `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband\**Favorites**` (Reg_Binary) and a couple others in that keys is getting updated as well. I am not sure how that can be updated.

Comment: **This method completely fails on Win 10 21H2 and Windows 11**. Would greatly appreciate if you could modify / update the answer to address the current state of play with Windows?

Answer (score 17):

Very nice!  I made a few small tweaks to that powershell example, I hope you don't mind :)

```
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True, HelpMessage="Target item to pin")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $Target
)
if (!(Test-Path $Target)) {
    Write-Warning "$Target does not exist"
    break
}

$KeyPath1  = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes"
$KeyPath2  = "*"
$KeyPath3  = "shell"
$KeyPath4  = "{:}"
$ValueName = "ExplorerCommandHandler"
$ValueData =
    (Get-ItemProperty `
        ("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\" + `
            "CommandStore\shell\Windows.taskbarpin")
    ).ExplorerCommandHandler

$Key2 = (Get-Item $KeyPath1).OpenSubKey($KeyPath2, $true)
$Key3 = $Key2.CreateSubKey($KeyPath3, $true)
$Key4 = $Key3.CreateSubKey($KeyPath4, $true)
$Key4.SetValue($ValueName, $ValueData)

$Shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$Folder = $Shell.Namespace((Get-Item $Target).DirectoryName)
$Item = $Folder.ParseName((Get-Item $Target).Name)
$Item.InvokeVerb("{:}")

$Key3.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath4)
if ($Key3.SubKeyCount -eq 0 -and $Key3.ValueCount -eq 0) {
    $Key2.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath3)
}
```

Comment: First off, THIS IS AWESOME! I hadn't checked back on this thread in a while, so I was super happy to see a PS solution.
@Skatterbrainz (or anyone), I am curious about two details.
1: At the end, there is a test to see if the shell key has any contents after the verb key has been deleted. But both of those keys are created earlier. Why the test rather than just using Remove-Item on the shell key with -recurse?

Comment: 2: If I use this code and the shortcut is already pinned, it gets unpinned. I kind of expected it to be left alone, i.e. the end result of the verb PinToTaskbar is the current state, so no need to do anything.

Comment: OK, regarding #2, I searched for the GUID found in HKLM, and there is a reference in HKCR with ImplementsVerbs=taskbarpin;taskbarunpin, so that explains the toggle behavior.

Comment: But it raises another question. Is the GUID set in stone, or is it different with different builds of Win10, different languages, etc? If it's always the same, couldn't that just be hard coded rather than finding it in HKLM first?

Comment: I apologize for the slow reply. I've been busy and haven't check back in awhile.  I think some GUID's are consistent but some have changed as well.  Mostly with changing features like "People" "Phone", etc.  But I'm not sure of which are which, exactly.

Comment: Hello, When I run this on a fresh Windows 2016, I see this error:

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> .\pinme.ps1 "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\pinme.ps1:23 char:1
+ $Key3 = $Key2.CreateSubKey($KeyPath3, $true)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: ugh... well, as of Windows 10 1809 at least, this doesn't appear to work like it did with 1803 and before.  I'm working on this to see what changed and if there's a fix.

Comment: works like a charm on Windows Server 2019 Datacanter - thanks

Comment: Windows 10 Pro version 20H2 and this doesn't work. I don't get an error. I don't notice any changes at all. I wonder if I just edited my registry in unknown ways.

Comment: No more luck on Windows 11.

Comment: **This method completely fails on Win 10 21H2 and Windows 11**. Would greatly appreciate if you could modify / update the answer to address the current state of play with Windows?

Comment: Fails on Windows 11: `(2023-12-03 16:54:02) [WARN ] [ShareMenu] menu init.
(2023-12-03 16:54:02) [WARN ] [ShareMenu] select file path len = 105
(2023-12-03 16:54:02) [WARN ] [ShareMenu] set menutype is SEND_TO_PHONE_MENU
(2023-12-03 16:54:02) [ERROR] [ShareMenu] phone not connect.
(2023-12-03 16:54:02) [WARN ] [HwShareMenu] start Show Hwshare Menu
(2023-12-03 16:54:02) [ERROR] [hwShareMenu] clause is not agree`

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem and I still do not know how to handle it, but this little command line tool does:

http://www.technosys.net/products/utils/pintotaskbar

You can use it in command line like that:

```
syspin "path/file.exe" c:5386
```

to pin a program to taskbar and

```
syspin "path/file.exe" c:5387
```

to unpin it. This works fine for me.

Comment: Given the existence of the Technosys EXE, it seems likely that there is an approach that would work in powerShell using some inlined C#. In my case I have a "commercial" need, in that I am managing a conference lab and we put the shortcuts for the session software on the task bar, refreshing between sessions using PowerShell. Hoping to license something if need be. Any suggestions?

Comment: FWIW, the desire to license stems from the Technosys EXE not being signed code, and I would rather pay for signed code than ask people to trust unsigned code.

Comment: Bump. Anyone found a way to do this in C#? Technosys wants $2k to license this tiny feature, which seems excessive.

Comment: True. Noone but Technosys managed to pin an app to Windows 10 taskbar yet.

Comment: check this link (first solution is not fine but works): https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1609288/pin-to-taskbar-no-longer-working-in-windows-10

Comment: @Gordon look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38880235/733760) for how to do it in C#

Comment: I've been using `syspin.exe` for a few years, and it seems to be the only way that works. **All of the PowerShell methods on this page completely fail on Win 10 21H2 and Windows 11** (presumably Microsoft changed something that broke these solutions). Would greatly appreciate if any C# solution that is found could be posted here so that PowerShell folks could get it in a version suitable for PowerShell scripts. 

Comment: SysPin is not working on Win11 22H2

Answer (score 9):

Here's Humberto's vbscript solution ported to PowerShell:

```
Param($Target)

$KeyPath1  = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes"
$KeyPath2  = "*"
$KeyPath3  = "shell"
$KeyPath4  = "{:}"
$ValueName = "ExplorerCommandHandler"
$ValueData = (Get-ItemProperty("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\" +
  "Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.taskbarpin")).ExplorerCommandHandler

$Key2 = (Get-Item $KeyPath1).OpenSubKey($KeyPath2, $true)
$Key3 = $Key2.CreateSubKey($KeyPath3, $true)
$Key4 = $Key3.CreateSubKey($KeyPath4, $true)
$Key4.SetValue($ValueName, $ValueData)

$Shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$Folder = $Shell.Namespace((Get-Item $Target).DirectoryName)
$Item = $Folder.ParseName((Get-Item $Target).Name)
$Item.InvokeVerb("{:}")

$Key3.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath4)
if ($Key3.SubKeyCount -eq 0 -and $Key3.ValueCount -eq 0) {
    $Key2.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath3)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In windows 10 Microsoft added a simple check before showing the verb. The name of the executable must be explorer.exe. It can be in any folder, just the name is checked. So the easy way in C# or any compiled program would be just to rename your program.

If that's not possible, you can fool the shell object in to thinking your program is called explorer.exe. I wrote a post [here](http://alexweinberger.com/main/pinning-network-program-taskbar-programmatically-windows-10/) on how to do it in C# by changing the Image Path in the PEB.

Comment: Alex, any chance you might be available to implement this in PowerShell? I am struggling at the moment, and sometimes the best answer is just to work with someone who gets it.

Comment: I'm not a PS expert, but can't you download the C# code in the link, compile it and call it from PS?

Comment: I could go the compile route, but I have been trying to keep my code visible, and hopefully educational. But inlining C# in PowerShell seems to be somewhat fraught with peril, so we'll see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Does your project have any type of license?

Comment: @HumbertoFreitas MIT license

Comment: Unfortunately, this trick stopped working in Windows 10 1903 May update

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac it seems this trick stopped working.. I wish I had the time to look into this!

Comment: Thank you anyway, maybe someone can figure it out at some point, your other answer posts were great still though.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to resurrect something so old.

I do not know how to do this in powershell, but in vbscript you can do this method that I developed. It works regardless of the system language.

Works on windows 8.x and 10.

**Script**

```
If WScript.Arguments.Count < 1 Then WScript.Quit
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFile    = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
sKey1      = "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\{:}\\"
sKey2      = Replace(sKey1, "\\", "\ExplorerCommandHandler")
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    KeyValue = .RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" & _
        "\CommandStore\shell\Windows.taskbarpin\ExplorerCommandHandler")

    .RegWrite sKey2, KeyValue, "REG_SZ"

    With WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        With .Namespace(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile))
            With .ParseName(objFSO.GetFileName(objFile))
                .InvokeVerb("{:}")
            End With
        End With
    End With

    .Run("Reg.exe delete """ & Replace(sKey1, "\\", "") & """ /F"), 0, True
End With
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Command line:**

```
pin and unpin: taskbarpin.vbs [fullpath]

Example: taskbarpin.vbs "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
```

Comment: I've tried all of these suggestions (ps1, vbs) on Win 10 vers 1903 and none worked. Anyone have an update on this?

Comment: Apparently MS deactivated the pin through this way. I have another script that uses the method of this solution and it still works, so it seems that she sees this pin shape as a security hole.

This solution still works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34182076/3732138

Comment: @julesverne, indeed, now Oct 2022, on Win 10 21H2 and Windows 11, none of the PowerShell or VBScript answers here work (2 years after you pointed it out).  Please can some of the geniuses on here that came up with these great answers, please update them to account for Microsoft breaking this? Hint: the only answer on this page that *works* is by using `syspin.exe`, and on that answer are links on how to do it in C#. If that can be translated to PowerShell, then this page will have working answers (currently this entire page is a honey-trap, people just waste time as no PowerShell here works).

Answer (score 6):

## Warning: None of the PowerShell / VBScript answers on this page work on Windows 10 21H2 or Windows 11 (and this functionality has been broken as far back as 2019).

Just putting this in bold so that people do not waste their time here. Hopefully someone can update the above (as they were great answers, but do not work any more due to Microsoft making changes, so hopefully some tweaking of the answers here can get them working again). As there is currently *no known method* of pinning apps to the Taskbar with PowerShell (since none of the solutions on this page work), the only solution that I know that works is the `syspin.exe` app. Please can the PowerShell answers be updated, as that would be far better than using `syspin`. Currently (and sadly), this page serves mostly as a "honey trap"; people come here, happy to find an answer to this, only to waste their time trying solutions that are all broken.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to @Humberto Freitas answer that i tweaked for my aim, you can try this vbscript in order to pin a program to taskbar using Vbscript in Windows 10.

***Vbscript : TaskBarPin.vbs***

```
Option Explicit
REM Question Asked here ==> 
REM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720595/pin-program-to-taskbar-using-ps-in-windows-10/34182076#34182076
Dim Title,objFSO,ws,objFile,sKey1,sKey2,KeyValue
Title = "Pin a program to taskbar using Vbscript in Windows 10"
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Ws     = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objFile    = DeQuote(InputBox("Type the whole path of the program to be pinned or unpinned !",Title,_
"%ProgramFiles%\windows nt\accessories\wordpad.exe"))
REM Examples
REM "%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
REM "%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
REM "%ProgramFiles%\windows nt\accessories\wordpad.exe"
REM "%Windir%\Notepad.exe"
ObjFile = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(ObjFile)
If ObjFile = "" Then Wscript.Quit()
sKey1      = "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\{:}\\"
sKey2      = Replace(sKey1, "\\", "\ExplorerCommandHandler")
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    KeyValue = .RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" & _
    "\CommandStore\shell\Windows.taskbarpin\ExplorerCommandHandler")
    .RegWrite sKey2, KeyValue, "REG_SZ"
    
    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        With .Namespace(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile))
            With .ParseName(objFSO.GetFileName(objFile))
                .InvokeVerb("{:}")
            End With
            
        End With
    End With
    .Run("Reg.exe delete """ & Replace(sKey1, "\\", "") & """ /F"), 0, True
End With
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Function DeQuote(S)
    If Left(S,1) = """" And Right(S, 1) = """" Then 
        DeQuote = Trim(Mid(S, 2, Len(S) - 2))
    Else 
        DeQuote = Trim(S)
    End If
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

***EDIT : on 24/12/2020***

Refer to :
[Where is Microsoft Edge located in Windows 10? How do I launch it?](https://superuser.com/questions/950435/where-is-microsoft-edge-located-in-windows-10-how-do-i-launch-it?answertab=active#tab-top)

Microsoft Edge should be in the taskbar. It is the blue 'e' icon.

[image: Taskbar]

If you do not have that or have unpinned it, you just need to repin it. Unfortunately the `MicrosoftEdge.exe` can not be run by double clicking and creating a normal shortcut will not work. You may have found it at this location.

[image: Location]

What you need to do is just search for Edge in the Start menu or search bar. Once you see Microsoft Edge, right click on it and **Pin to taskbar**.

[image: Search]

---

You can run the Microsoft Edge with this vbscript : ***Run-Micro-Edge.vbs***

```
CreateObject("wscript.shell").Run "%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Powershell Class using the above answers as motivation. I just put it into a module then imported into my other scripts.

```
using module "C:\Users\dlambert\Desktop\Devin PC Setup\PinToTaskbar.psm1"

[PinToTaskBar_Verb] $pin = [PinToTaskBar_Verb]::new();

$pin.Pin("C:\Windows\explorer.exe") 
$pin.Pin("$env:windir\system32\SnippingTool.exe") 
$pin.Pin("C:\Windows\explorer.exe") 
$pin.Pin("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe") 
$pin.Pin("C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe") 
$pin.Pin("$env:windir\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe")
```

Module below

```
class PinToTaskBar_Verb 
{
    [string]$KeyPath1  = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes"
    [string]$KeyPath2  = "*"
    [string]$KeyPath3  = "shell"
    [string]$KeyPath4  = "{:}"
    
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]$Key2 
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]$Key3
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]$Key4

    PinToTaskBar_Verb()
    {
        $this.Key2 = (Get-Item $this.KeyPath1).OpenSubKey($this.KeyPath2, $true)
    }
    

    [void] InvokePinVerb([string]$target)
    {
        Write-Host "Pinning $target to taskbar"
        $Shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
        $Folder = $Shell.Namespace((Get-Item $Target).DirectoryName)
        $Item = $Folder.ParseName((Get-Item $Target).Name)
        $Item.InvokeVerb("{:}")
    }



    [bool] CreatePinRegistryKeys()
    {
        $TASKBARPIN_PATH = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.taskbarpin";
        $ValueName = "ExplorerCommandHandler"
        $ValueData = (Get-ItemProperty $TASKBARPIN_PATH).ExplorerCommandHandler
        
        Write-Host "Creating Registry Key: $($this.Key2.Name)\$($this.KeyPath3)"
        $this.Key3 = $this.Key2.CreateSubKey($this.KeyPath3, $true)

        Write-Host "Creating Registry Key: $($this.Key3.Name)\$($this.KeyPath4)"
        $this.Key4 = $this.Key3.CreateSubKey($this.KeyPath4, $true)

        Write-Host "Creating Registry Key: $($this.Key4.Name)\$($valueName)"
        $this.Key4.SetValue($ValueName, $ValueData)

        return $true
    }

    [bool] DeletePinRegistryKeys()
    {
        Write-Host "Deleting Registry Key: $($this.Key4.Name)"
        $this.Key3.DeleteSubKey($this.KeyPath4)
        if ($this.Key3.SubKeyCount -eq 0 -and $this.Key3.ValueCount -eq 0) 
        {
            Write-Host "Deleting Registry Key: $($this.Key3.Name)"
            $this.Key2.DeleteSubKey($this.KeyPath3)
        }
        return $true
    }

    [bool] Pin([string]$target)
    {
        try
        {
            $this.CreatePinRegistryKeys()
            $this.InvokePinVerb($target)
        }
        finally
        {
            $this.DeletePinRegistryKeys()
        }
        return $true
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this by chance unpin from taskbar too, and from Windows 10 20H2 version? I'm having trouble getting anything to work to unpin programmatically from Windows 10 20H2 with all answers here and other posts I've tried. Curious if you know anything regarding this and if you have anything you confirmed works to unpin from taskbar programmatically using PS or anything really I can run from PS including C# code. Figured it'd be worth an ask to you if nothing else. From what I gather (and tested) Microsoft changed something so you can no longer do the unpin via the method people have written about.

Comment: Looks cool but didn't work for me on win10 pro 20H2..

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use [this Windows 10 feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar#sample-taskbar-configuration-added-to-start-layout-xml-file). It allows people to specify pinned programs (and other things) via an XML file.

Comment: Seem this won't work: see https://superuser.com/a/1117140