# How to get verb for pin to taskbar in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, powershell, windows-10

I'm trying to pin an exe to taskbar in windows 10. But I'm not able to find verb for pin/unpin to taskbar.

I have tried the same code on windows 7 and 8.1 machine, its working fine, but its not working on windows 10 machine.

VB Code:

```
Dim ShellApp, Desktop
    ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Desktop = ShellApp.NameSpace("C:\ProgramData\ABC.exe").Parsename("ABC.exe").invokeverb("taskbarpin")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was [reported](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1609288/pin-to-taskbar-no-longer-working-in-windows-10) already (see also [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31720595/1997232)).

And one possible solution (on the same page, re-posting it here):

> Posted by Misha Rudiy on 11/5/2015 at 7:30 AM
>
> For new OS installs you can still pin to the taskbar via the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TBDEn registry key.
>
> Example: In an SCCM Task Sequence, I have a batch script that runs after the "Setup Windows and Configuration Manager" step that basically contains reg-adds.
>
> Syntax (REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TBDEn" /v SBOEM0 /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%ALLUSERSPROFILE%%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Mozilla Firefox.lnk" /f)
>
> You can add additional links by adding values and incrementing SBOEM0 to SBOEM1 etc.
>
> Thanks to Wayne Ye http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185512/Programmatically-PIN-shortcut-onto-Taskbar-on-Win7.aspx for pointing this method out back in 2011.
>
> Somethings to note, there seems to be little public documentation on this. It most likely only works as a post imaging step (see my reference to SCCM), but I am not 100% sure. The above mentioned site states that it takes place during the DASH process. I wasn't able to find any documentation on how\when a DASH process works with Windows OSes. This may be information that is only privy to OEMS.