# Replacing pinned applications on taskbar using powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-office

Getting ready to upgrade our user base from Office 2016 MSI version to Office 2016 Click to Run. In testing we have found old shortcuts will all break with the new version. Trying to get some insight on how I can replace old pinned applications with the new ones using a powershell script.

I found this article on pinning new icons which has been helpful but can't find anything on replacing icons.

[Pin program to taskbar using PS in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720595/pin-program-to-taskbar-using-ps-in-windows-10)

Comment: Posting as a comment since it's a non-programmatic solution but you [can do this via GPO](https://eimajnamron.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/server-2012-rds-pin-applications-to-taskbar-with-group-policy/)

Answer (score -1):

I've used this for years, but I mostly deal with new profiles.

```
# import start menu
# https://4sysops.com/archives/pin-apps-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-10-1607-with-group-policy/

# powershell export-startlayout -path startmenu.xml -verbose

import-startlayout -layoutpath startmenu1703.xml -mountpath c:\ -verbose
```